# Is it possible to return data set instead of any mapped model class in MyBatis?

Tags: java, reflection, mybatis

I have scenario where I want to make dynamic query which myBatis supposed to support like as below :

```
    <select id=“someRecords” resultMap=“someRecordMap”>

        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEMP_TABLE;
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_TABLE(some_stub UUID);

        INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE (some_stub)
        select regexp_split_to_table(#{someIds},',')::uuid;

        SELECT wil.some_identifier_stub as identifier_stub
        ,wil.x
        ,wil.y
        ,wil.z
        ,wil.u
        ,wil.o
        ,msg.p
        FROM TABLE_A msg
        INNER JOIN TABLE_B wil ON msg.a_id = wil.b_id
        INNER JOIN TABLE_C est ON est.c_stub = wil.b_stub
        WHERE wil.unique_id = #{uniqueId} AND wil.b_type_id = #{b_TypeId}
        <if test="environment != null">
            <include refid="environmentCondition"></include>
        </if>
    </select>

    <sql id="environmentCondition">
        AND environment = #{environment}
    </sql>
```

But instead of someRecordMap, I want to return DataSet so that it become backward compatible with my existing code

So instead of suing myBatis XMl approach I just make custom approach using reflection and annotations like below :

Section : Dynamic Query Based on some condition like IGNORE_SOME_JOIN, IGNORE_SOME_STUB, IGNORE_SOME_EXT_FLAG

```
    @SqlQueries({@SqlQuery(name = "query1",
                query = "select a,b," +
                        "c,d,e,f,g,wil.h," +
                        " j,h,i " +
                        START_DELIMITER + " " + IGNORE_SOME_JOIN + " " +
                        " ,some_message" + END_DELIMITER +
                        " FROM  A_TABLE wil " +
                        START_DELIMITER + " " + IGNORE_SOME_JOIN + " " +
                        "LEFT OUTER JOIN B_TABLE wim on" +
                        " wil.unique_id = wim.unique_id" +
                        " and wim.created_date >= ?  and wim.created_date <= ?  " + END_DELIMITER +
                        " WHERE ( wil.created_date >= ? AND wil.created_date <= ? AND wil.primary_id = ? " +
                        START_DELIMITER + " " + IGNORE_SOME_STUB + " " +
                        " AND wil.unique_identifier_stub = ?::uuid " + END_DELIMITER +
                        START_DELIMITER + " " + IGNORE_SOME_EXT_FLAG +
                        " AND wil.some_ext_success_flag = ANY(?) " + END_DELIMITER + ")" +
                        "ORDER BY wil.created_date OFFSET ? LIMIT ? ")}
        )
```

*parsing logic for dynamic query be like* :

```
    abstract class ReportingQuery {
        private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReportingQuery.class);

        static final String START_DELIMITER = "#~";
        static final String END_DELIMITER = "#~";
        static final String REPLACEABLE_DELIMITER = "--";

        /**
         * Responsible to prepare final query after applying dynamic query criteria
         *
         * @param className     : ReportingQuery class reference
         * @param methodName    : Query method name
         * @param queryName     : Dynamic query
         * @param ignoreStrings : Criteria to be applied in dynamic query
         * @return : final static query after applying dynamic query criteria(ignoreStrings)
         */
        static Optional<String> getQuery(Class className, String methodName, String queryName, List<String> ignoreStrings) {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                Method[] methods = className.getDeclaredMethods();
                Optional<String> queryString = Optional.empty();
                if (Arrays.stream(methods).anyMatch(x -> x.getName().equals(methodName))) {
                    QueryExample.SqlQuery[] sqlQueries = Arrays.stream(methods)
                            .filter(x -> x.getName().equals(methodName))
                            .findFirst().get().getAnnotation(ReportingQuery.SqlQueries.class).value();
                    if (Arrays.stream(sqlQueries).anyMatch(x -> x.name().equals(queryName))) {
                        queryString = Optional.of(Arrays.stream(sqlQueries).filter(x -> x.name()
                                .equals(queryName)).findFirst().get().query());
                    }
                }

                String[] token = new String[0];
                if (queryString.isPresent()) {
                    token = queryString.get().split(START_DELIMITER);
                }


               ...... SOME logic to make query based on some dynamic condition

            return Optional.of(builder.toString());
        }

        /**
         *
         */
        @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
        @Target({ElementType.METHOD})
        @interface SqlQuery {
            String name();

            String query();
        }

        /**
         *
         */
        @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
        @Target({ElementType.METHOD})
        @interface SqlQueries {
            SqlQuery[] value();
        }
    }
```

So if I have condition IGNORE_SOME_JOIN then my final query with logic would be like

```
    select a,b,c,d,e,f,g,wil.h,j,h,i FROM  A_TABLE wil WHERE ( wil.created_date >= '2018-08-29T15:15:42.42'
            AND wil.created_date <= '2018-08-30T15:15:42.42' AND wil.acct_id = 2000017
             AND wil.unique_identifier_stub = 'a004f322-1003-40a7-a54b-f3b979744fd2'
             AND wil.some_ext_success_flag  = ANY('{"0","1"}')) ORDER BY wil.created_date OFFSET 0 LIMIT 500;
```

So with above I got query as string and I'll run  below code and get Result Set :

```
     PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query)) {
                    prepareStatement(prepareStatementAndQueryList, ps, con);
                    try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
                    DO SOMETHING WITH RESULT SET NOW
    }
    }
```

But I want to do this with MyBatis instead my own custom solution which would little error prone and might be not performance efficient as I have used much reflection here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible and is directly supported by mybatis. Here is an example from the [documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/java-api.html):

```
@SelectProvider(type = UserSqlBuilder.class, method = "buildGetUsersByName")
List<User> getUsersByName(String name);

class UserSqlBuilder {
  public static String buildGetUsersByName(final String name) {
    return new SQL(){{
      SELECT("*");
      FROM("users");
      if (name != null) {
        WHERE("name like #{value} || '%'");
      }
      ORDER_BY("id");
    }}.toString();
  }
}
```

In the example above `getUsersByName` is a mapper method and `UserSqlBuilder` is used by the mapper to generate SQL query text dynamically based on mapper parameters. It's exactly what you need and very similar to what `ReportingQuery` does.

You need to adapt your code so that your existing query generator confirms to `SelectProvider` API but this seems to be rather straightforward.

Comment: Thanks @Roman , this looks I'll get dynamic query with above but still it is SQL [Injection prone](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-dynamic-sql/docs/howItWorks.html)

I want dynamic binding of query params also with dynamic query behaviour, so it will be best fit for my use case of backward compatibility with the existing code which expects ResultSet as output

Comment: Still I am using my custom solution which described above :)

Comment: The solution with `SelectProvider` is not prone to SQL injection if do it properly (that is use parameters like `#value` in the example above).